# Apache virtual host based on CNAME

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, domain-name-system, virtualhost

Can I make a vhost on apache to respond to a cname request? For example:

A-record of example.com is 1.2.3.4
foo.example.com is a CNAME for example.com

in http.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName example.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost foo.example.com>
 ServerName foo.example.com
 DocumentRoot /foo/www
</VirtualHost>
```

apache starts fine and digests my conf, but when I visit foo.example.com I get the content in /var/www, not the one in /foo/www. I think I'm on the wrong track here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following snippet should work (without any warning):

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName foo.example.com
 DocumentRoot /foo/wwww
</VirtualHost>
```

Make sure you read the documentation on [Name-based Virtual Host Support](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html) to understand why it didn't work in the first place.

Comment: For those visitors whose eye's may be glazed from reading hundreds of forum posts and irrelevant results from Google searches:

The key part is including the "NameVirtualHost" directive that @joschi includes in his snippet above. Name-based virtual hosts don't work without a NameVirtualHost directive.

Comment: If `<VirtualHost secondary.ip:80>` is present as well, you need a `NameVirtualHost secondary.ip:80` as well. The `NameVirtualHost *:80` does not cover it... (And `<VirtualHost *:80>` does not seem to work on the secondary IP for additional VirtualHosts)

Answer (score 0):

I got it working like this:

```
NameVirtualHost _default_:80

<VirtualHost _default_:80>
  ServerName example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:80>
 ServerName foo.example.com
 DocumentRoot /foo/wwww
</VirtualHost>
```

Although this gives a warning at http start:

```
[warn] NameVirtualHost _default_:80 has no VirtualHosts
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding the port number on the foo.example.com vhost ?

ie:

```
<VirtualHost foo.example.com:80>
    ServerName foo.example.com
    DocumentRoot /foo/www
</VirtualHost>
```